# How to call onchage function in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I call onchage function in another function?

My first function:

```
$('.input-number').change(function() {
// my code here
}
```

and my second function:

```
$(function(){ 
        $(document).on('change', '.destination', function() {
            // my code here
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'myurl',
                    data: mydata,
                    type: "post",
                    success: function(data){
                        // my code here
                        // here i must call $('.input-number').change(function()) to refresh my first code        
                    }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [trigger the event programmatically](https://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/) using [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method.

```
$('.input-number').trigger('change');

// or use shorthandler
$('.input-number').change();
```

Comment: yeah but this just feels wrong, he should scrap this and start new P.S. I meant OP not Pranav :)

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev I disagree with that statement.  Saying someone should start over completely based off of "feels wrong" without providing reasons for it, well, **that** feels wrong.

Comment: @Taplar and I respect your opinion but if you are not able to see why is wrong then you haven't read read his code and question.

Comment: His on change does something.  From another place he's changing the value through code, and he wants the on change logic to happen there.  trigger() is a legit way to do that.

Comment: hm sorry still does not make any sense to me :) but I guess you know better so I am not going to comment further

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev : he just want to fire the code inside the event handler.... in order fire we just need to fire the event..... that is the purpose of trigger method.....

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev : is there any reason to feel its wrong? ... if yes, then let us fix that as well :)

Comment: Pranav, of course that is beyond crystal clear and I am aware of trigger but the main question is why he needs to do it, this code is just not making any sense.. instead using some functions,objects around and stuff.

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev : Yes he can use a common function.. but still scope is really an issue here.... in case both codes are in different scope?....  in that case we need to define it in global scope.... that's not a better approach ...... anyway it depends upon the code.... the `trigger()` would help to execute all the handlers attached to that particular event, so it would be the better approach at this scenario...(only my assumption :) )

Comment: Yep, the multiple handlers thing makes sense :) still this approach bugs me, thanks for taking the time to explain P.S. what bugs me is triggering human event just to make your code work :)

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev : in some case triggering event is necessary .. for eg. When we are updating input element content dynamically.... At that point we need to trigger it manually..... Inside most of the plugins... Trigger is using widely.... So in my view its  not a bug... :)